# slds components in salesforce 1 are non responsive

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning, lightning-apps

I have a table as component which I want to be responsive to view port or S1. It is however, not acting responsive in S1 or in view ports of various dimensions. I have made it have required interfaces implemented. Also, after adding it to lightning page through app builder and adding that page to S1 navigation, it still is non-responsive.  I've removed unnecessary attribute from the markup to make it precise, if any is missing then that is just copy paste mistake.

Following is the markup:

```
<aura:component controller="AdminPageComponentController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">


<aura:dependency resource="markup://c:Spinner" />
<aura:dependency resource="markup://c:CustomSettingValue" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="settingType" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="customSetting" type="TimeTrackerConfigSettings__c[]" />


<div class="slds ">
    <div aura:id="errorMsgID" class="slds-hide">
        <c:ErrorLabelComponent errorMsg="{!v.errorMsg}" />
    </div>
    <article class="slds-card slds-is-relative" >
        <!--spinner-->
        <lightning:spinner aura:id="spinnerDiv" variant="brand" size="small"/>

        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--col-bordered slds-scrollable" role="grid">
            <!--Table head dynamically displaying fields for selected view-->
            <thead>
                <!--Dynamic display of field labels as columns of table-->
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                    <aura:iteration var="fieldName" items="{!v.fieldNamesList}">
                        <th aura:id="colHeader" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" color-background="#f4f6f9" title="{!fieldName}">{!fieldName}</div>
                        </th>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!--Table contents dynamically displayed for selected view-->
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration aura:id="iterationID" var="setting" items="{!v.customSetting}">
                    <tr>
                        <aura:iteration var="fieldName" items="{!v.fieldAPINamesList}">
                            <td >
                                <div class="slds-truncate">
                                    <c:CustomSettingValue setting="{!setting}" fieldName="{!fieldName}" settingType="{!v.settingType}"/>
                                </div> 
                            </td>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </article>
```

This table only scrolls vertically and not horizontally. Similarly other components like modal are not responsive(Modal is not even scrolling vertically). There are browser scroll bars if used on desktop browser, hence it is looking fine on desktop though. Is there anything more we need to add to a component to make it compatible with S1?

Comment: `slds-scrollable` is not compatible with S1. And moreover, there is nothing much you did in the code to make it responsive. Also paste your Modal's code.

Comment: I am new to this responsive world...I was assuming that salesforce lightning framework takes care of responsivenes...but if we need to code something to make it responsive, I will surely research on the subject. Any reference links on the same are appreciated.

Comment: Lightning Design System has a bunch of style classes which can be applied in specific manner to make the UI responsive. [This URL](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) is a good start. Go to component->Utility->Grid.